# 25% CPU Usage at idle--Windows 10 system interrupts

Tags: windows-10, drivers, cpu-usage

Thanks in advance for your help.

Since I've upgraded to Windows 10, I've noticed that my CPU idles around 25%--specifically, one core hovers around 80-90% while the others are around 3-9%. I've run the Windows Performance Monitor Report, LatencyMon, and the Windows Performance Recorder and Analyzer. All of them point to abnormally high system interrupts as being the culprit. It lists 'rspLLL64.sys', 'USBPORT.SYS', and 'storport.sys' as having unusually high DPC and ISR counts.

I've looked in Device Manager, and I can neither update those drivers nor roll them back to an earlier version. Updating my BIOS is problematic since the latest update 1) came in 2012, and 2) is a beta version; the final version was never released.

I've tried talking to Microsoft tech support, who weren't much help. No, my computer isn't infected; yes, I've tried restarting (several times). I've disabled a lot of the native Win 10 apps. I've tried restarting in safe mode, and the problem still persists. If anyone can please give me an idea of what to do or where to go, I'd really appreciate it.

Hardware:
CPU: AMD Phenom II X4 955 BE
Mainboard: GA-MA790XT-UD4P (BIOS ver F8)
RAM: (4 x 2GB) Crucial DDR3-1066
System Drive (SSD): Sammsung EVO 840 500GB
Storage Drives (HDD): Samsung Spinpoint F3 HD502HJ 500GB; Western Digital Caviar Black WD10 01FALS-00J7B1 1TB
DVD: TSSTcorp TS-H662A DVD-RW
Graphics: XFX Radeon HD 6850
Audio: Onboard
WiFi: Belkin F5D8053 N Wireless USB Adapter

ETL file is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/472dfnnv359hfj4/BLACKFLAGG.10-12-2016.19-37-52.etl.zip?dl=0).

Comment: share the generated ETL file and I'll analyze it

Comment: @magicandre1981: Edited post to include .etl file. Thanks again.

Comment: ok, I posted an answer of what I saw

Comment: any update? Have you updated the driver?

Comment: @magicandre1981--That did the trick. I had to update manually via Device Manager from ver 1.2.001.0376 to ver 1.3.1.276, and, for anyone else who has this issue, the Windows 8 x64 version of amd_sata.sys (WB64A folder) works fine for Windows 10 x64.  

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CPU usage of the [Interrupts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt) (ISR) come from the AMD AHCI/SATA driver `amd_sata.sys` in version `1.2.001.0376`.

```
Line #, DPC/ISR, Module, Stack, Count, Process, Weight (in view) (ms), TimeStamp (s), % Weight
11, , ,   |    |    |    ntoskrnl.exe!KiScanInterruptObjectList, 8350, , 8.338,228380, , 2,60
12, , ,   |    |    |    ntoskrnl.exe!KiCallInterruptServiceRoutine, 8350, , 8.338,228380, , 2,60
13, , ,   |    |    |    storport.sys!RaidpAdapterInterruptRoutine, 8350, , 8.338,228380, , 2,60
14, , ,   |    |    |    amd_sata.sys!<PDB not found>, 8350, , 8.338,228380, , 2,60
15, , ,   |    |    |    |- amd_sata.sys!<PDB not found>, 6218, , 6.208,977178, , 1,93
16, , ,   |    |    |    |    |- amd_sata.sys!<PDB not found><itself>, 6217, , 6.207,976911, , 1,93
```

Install the [latest AMD driver](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop/legacy?product=legacy4&os=Windows%2010%20-%2064) fro your old Socket AM3 board and hope this driver fixes it.